# Implementing a simple substitution cipher using VBA

Tags: vba, replace

I am trying to make a program that changes letters in a string and i keep running into the obvious issue of if it changes a value, say it changes A to M, when it gets to M it will then change that M to something else, so when i run the code to change it all back it converts it as if the letter was originally an M not an A.

Any ideas how to make it so the code doesnt change letters its already changed?

as for code ive just got about 40 lines of this (im sure theres a cleaner way to do it but im new to vba and when i tried select case it would only change one letter and not go through all of them)

```
Text1.value = Replace(Text1.value, "M", "E")
```

Comment: Are you trying to change EVERY letter to something else, or just selected letters?

Comment: every letter will turn into something different, at least thats the goal

Comment: Oh!  So you're trying to make a code decrypter of sorts?

Comment: pretty much, i got bored and wanted to experiment with things. seemed like a good place to start on day 3 of working with vba haha

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
Dim strToChange As String
strToChange = "This is my string that will be changed"
Dim arrReplacements As Variant

arrReplacements = Array(Array("a", "m"), _
                        Array("m", "z"), _
                        Array("s", "r"), _
                        Array("r", "q"), _
                        Array("t", "a"))

Dim strOutput As String
strOutput = ""
Dim i As Integer
Dim strCurrentLetter As String

For i = 1 To Len(strToChange)
    strCurrentLetter = Mid(strToChange, i, 1)
    Dim arrReplacement As Variant

    For Each arrReplacement In arrReplacements
        If (strCurrentLetter = arrReplacement(0)) Then
            strCurrentLetter = Replace(strCurrentLetter, arrReplacement(0), arrReplacement(1))
            Exit For
        End If
    Next

    strOutput = strOutput & strCurrentLetter
Next
```

Here is the output:

```
Thir ir zy raqing ahma will be chmnged
```

Comment: Showing the contents of `strOutput` might help future readers see more clearly what your code ultimately does.

Comment: Okay, that's fine.  Done.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was show *us* (the Stack Overflow readers) what the final string is.

Comment: it works, tho im not sure whats making it side step the issue i was having, the only thing i can guess is your somehow using the array to change all of the values at the same time to avoid the issue.

Comment: @user1787114 -- The reason it works is because it takes it one letter at a time and determines what letter swap, if any, is required on each letter.  Take the word "amphibian"; it will look at the first character, "a", and change that to "m", then it will proceed to the next letter, "m", and change that to "z", and so on.

Comment: @GordThompson -- You're right, of course.  I missed the obvious point of what you were saying.

Comment: oh ok, so its going letter by letter instead of running through the entire thing in one go, then changing what letter it looks for and running again, that makes a lot more sense haha

THANKS!

Comment: @user1787114 -- If you're new to VBA, I would suggest you set a breakpoint and observe what the code is doing line-by-line.  In the VBA editor, activate the "Locals" window which will show you all the current variables and their values while debugging.  This is available under "View" > "Locals Window".

Answer (score 1):

Loop through it using the MID function.  Something like:

```
MyVal = text1.value
For X = 1 to Len(MyVal)
  MyVal = Replace(Mid(MyVal, X, 1), "M", "E")
  X = X + 1
Next X
```

EDIT: OK upon further light, I'm gonna make one change.  Store the pairs in a table.  Then you can use DLookup to do the translation, using the same concept:

```
MyVal = text1.value
For X = 1 to Len(MyVal)
    NewVal = DLookup("tblConvert", "fldNewVal", "fldOldVal = '" & Mid(MyVal, X, 1) & "")
    MyVal = Replace(Mid(MyVal, X, 1), Mid(MyVal, X, 1), NewVal)
  X = X + 1
Next X
```

Comment: This only addresses one letter change.  The OP indicated that there will be multiple swaps, e.g. "it changes A to M, when it gets to M it will then change that M to something else"

Comment: whats stopping it from changing values later. for example it was was changing E to M instead, when it gets to M (some letters could be E that changed to M and some could be M that havent changed) whats stopping it from changing the M that is an M because it changed from E, if that makes any sense

Comment: @Johnny -- In fact, your code is equivalent to just using `Text1.value = Replace(Text1.value, "M", "E")`

Comment: @roryap - Yeah, he didn't really specify that until after I provided this answer...  But you can still use the concept.  In fact, if he stores the pair in a table, he can substitute a DLookup in and get the values that way.

Comment: Yes he did.  The OP says "it changes A to M, when it gets to M it will then change that M to something else"

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way that uses less loops

```
Public Function Obfuscate(sInput As String) As String

    Dim vaBefore As Variant
    Dim vaAfter As Variant
    Dim i  As Long
    Dim sReturn As String

    sReturn = sInput
    vaBefore = Split("a,m,s,r,t", ",")
    vaAfter = Split("m,z,r,q,a", ",")

    For i = LBound(vaBefore) To UBound(vaBefore)
        sReturn = Replace$(sReturn, vaBefore(i), "&" & Asc(vaAfter(i)))
    Next i

    For i = LBound(vaAfter) To UBound(vaAfter)
        sReturn = Replace$(sReturn, "&" & Asc(vaAfter(i)), vaAfter(i))
    Next i

    Obfuscate = sReturn

End Function
```

It turns every letter into an ampersand + the replacement letters ascii code. Then it turns every ascii code in the replacement letter.

It took about 5 milliseconds vs 20 milliseconds for the nested loops.