# Simple cipher in VBA in Excel using a table for substitution

Tags: vba, excel

I want to write a simple cipher in Excel which would take a text from a cell, substitute each letter for a number from adjacent column and then put the output in another cell. Can't get VLOOKUP to work - it works as a formula, but somehow can't get it to work inside VBA code. Tried to do a simple procedure first that would do this for one character (adding a loop later would be easy), but it doesn't work. It compiles, but when I run it (press a button I assigned it to) I get "#N/A" in the result cell.

```
Sub Zakoduj()

Dim Literka As String
Dim Liczba As Variant
Dim ColumnToTake As Integer

ColumnToTake = 1 ' Liczby

On Error Resume Next
Err.Clear

Literka = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value

Liczba = Application.VLookup(Literka, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A5:B39"), ColumnToTake, False)

If Err.Number = 0 Then
    Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = Liczba
Else
    Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = Err.Number
End If

End Sub
```

The range contains number and characters as follows:

```
Kod Litera
16  A
73  B
12  C
40  D
70  E
etc. etc.
```

Couldn't find a tutorial that would explain how to do this...

Comment: `Application.worksheetfunction.VLookup`  have you stepped through before and after the vlookup, try removing the error trapping to, I think the function fails rather than return n/a maybe?

Comment: Aren't your columns back to front?  Your current `VLookup` is looking in your column called `Kod` for the value you are getting from `Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value` - but it sounds like you want to lookup from the column called `Litera`, so you probably need to switch those columns around.  (And you are also returning the value from the first column so, if a match occurs, you are just returning the same value you looked up - you will probably want to set `ColumnToTake` to be `2`.)

Comment: You could try [using arrays](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22050148/7690982) also, because they are really optimized. And the examples set the replace function to replace your cipher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a modified version. Note that the values are in A1:B6 on sheet 1

```
Option Explicit

Sub Zakoduj()
    Dim Literka As Integer
    Dim Liczba As String
    Dim ColumnToTake As Integer

    ColumnToTake = 2    ' Liczby
    Literka = Sheets("Sheet2").Range("B2").Value
    Liczba = "Value not found"  'If value is not found

    On Error Resume Next
    Liczba = Application.WorksheetFunction.VLookup(Literka, Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:B6"), ColumnToTake, False)
    On Error GoTo 0    'Always reset error handling after On Error Resume Next

    Sheet2.Range("B6").Value = Liczba
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks for help. However, it still doesn't work... "Liczba" doesn't change from "Value not found" after calling VLookup. I don't know why, as everything is correct - the range etc.

Comment: OK, got it! Vlookup look ups only the first column!

Comment: VLookup looks in the first column of the range specified and grabs the value from the next column specified by ColumnToTake. If you set ColumnToTake to 1 you'll get the same output as input.