# VBA help to convert number into alphabet

Tags: vba, navbar

Can you help me with the code please using vba?

I want to convert below numeric into alphabet?
The conversion code is GODFATHER. Where 1 stand for G, 2 stand for O, 3 stand for D.

Comment: Can you elaborate what you want to achieve? And what have you tried so far?

Comment: 123456789 as clear as your explanation, right?

Comment: Just build a loop and do it yourself. Ask ChatGPT or something.

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you are trying to replicate a Vigenere cypher - see this Wiki article [Visual Basic for Applications/Simple Vigenere Cipher in VBA](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Visual_Basic_for_Applications/Simple_Vigenere_Cipher_in_VBA)
and/or this SO post with some other solutions
[Implementing a simple substitution cipher using VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22049805/implementing-a-simple-substitution-cipher-using-vba)